# Creating new column informing how many unique values there are in multiple columns

Tags: r

So, I have a dataframe that looks like this, but with 10k rows:

| studentID | school_ID_1 | school_ID_2 | school_ID_3 | school_ID_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5555 | 3321 | 3311 | 3311 | 3311 |
| 5544 | 3347 | 3326 | 3350 | 3347 |
| 5533 | 3364 | 3314 | 3328 | 3302 |
| 5566 | 3389 | 3351 | 3379 | 3384 |
| 5577 | 3312 | 3303 | 3320 | 3320 |

If my data had only one student, using the following command:

```r
dep_edu2016_4x = data.frame(table(unlist(dep_edu2016_4x)))
```

Would tell me how many times this student changed schools in a year through the number of rows the table would return, minus the studentID row. I've already made a dummy to know if they've changed schools, now I need a solution to create a new column informing me how many times each student changed schools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
dep_edu2016_4x$unique_schools <- apply(
  subset(dep_edu2016_4x, select = school_ID_1:school_ID_4), 1,
  function(z) length(unique(z)) - 1L)
dep_edu2016_4x
#   studentID school_ID_1 school_ID_2 school_ID_3 school_ID_4 unique_schools
# 1      5555        3321        3311        3311        3311              1
# 2      5544        3347        3326        3350        3347              2
# 3      5533        3364        3314        3328        3302              3
# 4      5566        3389        3351        3379        3384              3
# 5      5577        3312        3303        3320        3320              2
```

Walk-through:

- `subset(...)` is one way to extract just the columns we need, including a range of columns; we could easily have started with `dep_edu2016_4x[,-1]` to select all except the `studentID`, but (1) I don't assume there are no other columns; and even if this is your whole dataset, then (2) once we add that column, we cannot recalculate it without biasing it with that additional column.
- `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN)` operates on each row (`MARGIN=1`) of the dataset (`X=x`), and applies the function (`FUN`) to that data. In this case, for each row it returns a single integer.
- `length(unique(z)) - 1L` calculates the number of distinct schools minus 1, a good proxy for the number of changes.

The count of school-changes is slightly incorrect, though: if a student starts at school `3321`, changes to `3311`, then changes *back* to `3321`, then `length(unique(.))-1L` will not work. (This appears to be the case for student `5544`.) We'll need something a little more robust if you want to guard against that:

```r
changes <- function(z) if (length(z)) sum(z[-1] != z[-length(z)]) else 0L
dep_edu2016_4x$schools_changes <- apply(subset(dep_edu2016_4x, select = school_ID_1:school_ID_4), 1, changes)
dep_edu2016_4x
#   studentID school_ID_1 school_ID_2 school_ID_3 school_ID_4 unique_schools schools_changes
# 1      5555        3321        3311        3311        3311              1               1
# 2      5544        3347        3326        3350        3347              2               3
# 3      5533        3364        3314        3328        3302              3               3
# 4      5566        3389        3351        3379        3384              3               3
# 5      5577        3312        3303        3320        3320              2               2
```

Comment: Thx! This solves it, but in this case I wouldn't need to remove 1 because the selected columns are excluding the studentID.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, see my recent edit. The `- 1L` is to better reflect the number of school changes, where a `0` indicates that there was only one school id. This means the column name is certainly misleading, it should not be `- 1L` if we name it as such. But the edit for `$schools_changes` should better reflect what you said you needed.

Comment: You're right, thank you for the walk-through, the schools_changes is exactly what I need!